# default.asp file web.config file and http:// to redirect https:// not working

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-config

Please can anyone advise me as to how I can configure a default.asp file a web.config file to make a permanent redirect from http: to https: ? The help from 1and1 advised to make a default.asp file and add the following:

```
<%EnableSessionState=False
host = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")

if host = "yourdomain.com" or host = "www.yourdomain.com" then
response.redirect("https://www.yourdomain.com/index.html")

else
response.redirect("https://www.yourdomain.com/error.htm")

end if
%>
```

However this bit of code only works if I type in the url as www.yourdomain.com/default.asp or yourdomain.com/default.asp so the redirect is  working but it leads me to believe that I would have to write a redirect rule for every page of the site - but I cannot get it to work for the root document, my web.config file is set up as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<defaultDocument enabled="true">
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="index.aspx" />
    <add value="index.asp" />
    <add value="index.htm" />
    <add value="index.html" />
    <add value="home.aspx" />
    <add value="home.asp" />
    <add value="home.htm" />
    <add value="home.html" />
    <add value="default.aspx" />
    <add value="default.asp" />
    <add value="default.htm" />
    <add value="default.html" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>

<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/x-font-opentype"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />    
    <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.24:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

I have modified the default.asp file in the root folder to:

```
<%EnableSessionState=False
host = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")

if host = "patchworktiles.net" or host = "www.patchworktiles.net" then
response.redirect("https://patchworktiles.net/")

else
response.redirect("https://patchworktiles.net/error.htm")

end if
%>
```

I would rather have a bit of code that ignores the any of the url after the / so that the page http://patchworktiles.net/anynameyoulike.html or http://www.patchworktiles.net/anynameyoulike.html would redirect to https://patchworktiles.net/anynameyoulike.html

Comment: So implement a rewrite rule, or add logic somewhere that runs on every request such as Application_BeginRequest in your global application class.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, I have discovered that the hosting company for our shared hosting does not allow this sort of thing!!! and they have provided the ability to do this through a .htaccess file which seemed a bit odd as we have windows hosting.

Comment: They aren't going to prevent you from adding redirect login in your global.asax.

Comment: Thanks again but the rewrite module is not installed and they won't enable it. I appreciate your assistance on this but after a long conversation with the host they got it to work with a .htaccess file! I was surprised as I only thought this would work with a linux server running apache and not a IIS 7.5  on windows server 2012. 1and1 are quite a large company so I would thought that they would allow windows servers to use the appropriate modules.